# how to select all children and grand children of a node in sql / oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

For instance if I have following table with this particular data:

```
Table X 

Node_ID  ParentNode_ID
----     ----
1        -
2        1
3        1
4        2
5        2
6        4
7        5
8        6
9        8
```

and I need a query to select children and grand children (and grand grand children...) of node '2', meaning following result:

```
children_of_node2
------
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

how can I do it with a select query and **not using** functions or declaring variables in oracle SQL?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  You do this either with `connect` or recursive CTEs.

Comment: @GordonLinoff im using apex 5.1 on oracle 12c (12.1), thanks I didn't know about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an elaboration on Gordon Linoff's comment.
Here are some examples.
First create the table and test data:

```
CREATE TABLE X (
  NODE_ID       NUMBER,
  PARENTNODE_ID NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO X VALUES (1, NULL);
INSERT INTO X VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO X VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO X VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO X VALUES (5, 2);
INSERT INTO X VALUES (6, 4);
INSERT INTO X VALUES (7, 5);
INSERT INTO X VALUES (8, 6);
INSERT INTO X VALUES (9, 8);
```

Then a first example, via `CONNECT BY`:
Create the query for node 2:

```
SELECT
  NODE_ID,
  (LEVEL -1) AS DISTANCE_FROM_ANCESTOR
FROM X
WHERE LEVEL > 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR NODE_ID = PARENTNODE_ID
START WITH NODE_ID = 2
ORDER BY 2 ASC, 1 ASC;
```

And test it:

```
NODE_ID  DISTANCE_FROM_ANCESTOR  
4        1                       
5        1                       
6        2                       
7        2                       
8        3                       
9        4
```

A second example, via recursive CTE:

Create the query:

```
WITH RECURSION_CTE(NODE_ID, DISTANCE_FROM_ANCESTOR)
AS
(SELECT
   NODE_ID,
   0 AS DISTANCE_FROM_ANCESTOR
 FROM X
 WHERE NODE_ID = 2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
   X.NODE_ID,
   RECURSION_CTE.DISTANCE_FROM_ANCESTOR + 1 AS DISTANCE_FROM_ANCESTOR
 FROM X
   INNER JOIN RECURSION_CTE ON X.PARENTNODE_ID = RECURSION_CTE.NODE_ID
)
SELECT
  NODE_ID,
  DISTANCE_FROM_ANCESTOR
FROM RECURSION_CTE
WHERE DISTANCE_FROM_ANCESTOR > 0
ORDER BY 2 ASC, 1 ASC;
```

And test it:

```
NODE_ID  DISTANCE_FROM_ANCESTOR  
4        1                       
5        1                       
6        2                       
7        2                       
8        3                       
9        4
```